# database schema for periodically store record for user

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I'm trying to come up with database schema to efficiently store data that periodically changes (maybe every 2 months or so). Let's say I have USER table that contains some information about users and every 2 month I want to store some of user information into other table, called RECORD. But then I thought it was very inefficient because that Record table will become larger (depends on how big user table is). For instance, if I have 1 million rows in user table, then record table will increase 1 millions every 2 months. Is this approach ok or is there better way to achieve this sort of system?

Comment: Can you provide a schema for each of the proposed tables? What is the purpose of duplicating the data and storing it long term? Do you need to keep the historical data for some reason?

Comment: yea I want to keep it as historical record for different purpose and data in USER will be changed after data is duplicated into other table

Comment: The approach you describe is fine if you're trying to maintain historical data. There isn't any way around the fact that it will require a lot of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ensure that whatever data you are storing is not redundant. If you are just wanting to view whatever data based on the user table then a view may be more appropriate